# How to reference a deconstructed value tuple without making a copy of it

Tags: c#

I have a method that manipulates a value tuple with multiple fields. That tuple is returned from another method and deconstructed,
in order to simplify further usages of its fields:

```
var (a, b, c) = GetValueTuple();
```

However, now I need to pass the entire tuple down to another method that expects it:

```
private void ExpectsTuple((a, b, c) tuple) { ... }

this.ExpectsTuple(/* need to pass tuple here */);
```

Is there an easy or clean way to "reconstruct" or pass down the entire tuple structure, without having to create a new one? I tried to name the tuple but that throws a compilation error:

```
var (a, b, c) tuple = GetValueTuple();
```

I know I could just do `ExpectsTuple((a, b, c))` but I wonder if that's gonna unnecessarily create a copy of my structure and if there's a cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you deconstruct it without storing the original; the original *is gone*; maybe store the original? i.e. `var tuple = GetValueTuple()`? You can then either access `tuple.Foo` etc, or just deconstruct it *afterwards*:

So:

```cs
var tuple = GetValueTuple();
var (a, b, c) = tuple;
// not shown: something involving a, b, c
// ...
ExpectsTuple(tuple);
```

or

```cs
var tuple = GetValueTuple();
// not shown: something involving tuple.Foo, tuple.Bar, etc
// ...
ExpectsTuple(tuple);
```

---

Edit: the following paragram may be incorrect; `in` may have been fine here; leaving for completeness, but maybe the trick would have been:

```cs
void ExpectsTuple(in (...the tuple type...) tuple)
{...}
// ...
ExpectsTuple(tuple); // the "in" here is implicit
```

---

As for creating a copy of the structure: it is going to do that **either way** - because of the stack semantics. The only question is how efficiently it can do it (does it have to execute a constructor? or is it just a blit?). Note that you can't use `in` to avoid this extra copy, because value-tuples are **not** `readonly struct`, so using the `in` will simply copy the tuple on the stack and then pass the address of the copy; you might as well just pass the copy on the stack. Technically you could use `ref` to avoid the copy, but... that is awkward, and probably not worth it in most cases. It also leaves your code at the mercy of whatever `ExpectsTuple(ref tuple)` chooses to do to the data.

Personally, I'd use the `tuple.Foo` etc approach; since tuples provide direct access to the fields, this is actually more direct than it might look, especially after the JIT has done what it needs.

---

From comments:

> Could you elaborate on "how efficiently it can do it (does it have to execute a constructor? or is it just a blit?)"

What I mean here is: when you just pass a pre-existing value, all it has to do is load the value from the stack - which is just a fast memory copy; however, if you've deconstructed it, it needs to *reconstruct* it, which means: running the `ValueTuple<,,>` constructor - with whatever logic that has; you can see that [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+BYAUAAQEwCM2OAzAAT5kAK2A3tmYxStQIYDO7AIgJaxgAXABQBKBk3pYm0sgDdWUMgICuABwA2MMgF4yAcRgCAaq3XKYAFTWbRAbnEyKBAJxCVGmADoAQutaqReylHMgBRBFUYQXYrDzdrGECHMgBfZOScFi4oiAA7dgEoZUEAQVyAEwAlHPzC4uExYMZJELkFMiFWABoyYB6wER19QxMzSwS7ZOkcFyEBoNbwyOjYm06evrIBpKbU9N2hHlyBMgAxCAgerlYBSx4AWy1vBR6ZgAYyX39Bg2NTc1WMFEUyY2gAfEoABZQCAAdzIuRg8IAchABABJe4eR7HGDlcJgGCqAQ8PKTXYZFhLKICGITQ7HM4XK43O6PT4vJwfL4BMgAfUarXBUJh8MRKLRmOxMFx+IQhOJpNy5JSQA==), by looking at the difference between `PassDirect` and `DeconstructAndReconstruct` *on the right hand side* (which is an interpretation of the code *after* the compiler has finished with it). You can see that `ExpectsTuple((a, b, c))` ends up running `ExpectsTuple(new ValueTuple<int, DateTime, string>(item, item2, item3))`; the [code for this constructor](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/ValueTuple.cs,657) isn't complicated, but it is a *lot* more complicated than just "load the value I already knew about".

I should also clarify: the code in the right hand pane *isn't exactly right* - there isn't *actually* another local with the value; to see what *actually* happens, you need to [look at the IL view](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwFgAoAAQCYBGE0gZgAIL6AFEgbxPq8ZRYEMAzgIAi2WGAwAKAJSduHYtyX0Abnyj0MAVwAOuGPQC89AOIwMANT64tMACq79MgNxzljSgE5J2vTAB0AEK4fDrSroru9ACiCDowEgIOfj6OMOFu9AC+mZmkvMIJEAB2AhhQWhIAgsUAJgBKRaXllVKykVwKUarq9JJ8aPTAg2DSRqbmVjb2aS6ZSqRekqMR3bHxiclO/YPD9KMZHdm5R5LYxRj0AGIQEIPCfBj22AC2BoHqg4sADPTBoWMzJZrLYtjAZPNuIYAHyaAAWUAgAHd6MUYCiAHIQDAASRefjeFxgtViYBgOgw2BKcyOeV46wSGCSszOF2ut3uj2ebz+nw8v3+YXoAH12t0YfDESi0ZjsXiCTAiSSEGSKVTijSskA===) - the actual local variables are declared at the top; see:

```
        .locals init (
            [0] valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.ValueTuple`3<int32, valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.DateTime, string> tuple
        )
```

and

```
        .locals init (
            [0] int32 a,
            [1] valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.DateTime b,
            [2] string c
        )
```

Note that the second one does *not* have both, i.e. it isn't

```
        .locals init (
            [0] valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.ValueTuple`3<int32, valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.DateTime, string> tuple
            [1] int32 a,
            [2] valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.DateTime b,
            [3] string c
        )
```

(despite that being what the C# view would suggest)

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate on "how efficiently it can do it (does it have to execute a constructor? or is it just a blit?)"? How do I determine which one it is? Can I force it to blit or is that a runtime thing?

Comment: *"so using the in will simply copy the tuple on the stack and then pass the address of the copy"* -- it won't copy it when it passed it in, the defensive copy happens at the point that a method is called which requires it. (A `readonly struct` is just shorthand for making all members readonly)

Comment: @canton7 hmmm; you might be right there - I'd need to think harder than I care to right now!

Comment: However, deconstructing a ValueTuple does make a copy of the ValueTuple in this case, although I'm not entirely sure why... Accessing one of its members is fine.

Comment: @canton7 the `dup`s ? looks like it is trying to avoid reserving a *permanent* chunk on the stack (`stloc`, `ldloc[.a]`), by using the ephemeral portion via `dup`, at the expense of some extra blits; it does, however, make we wonder about the design of custom deconstructors - should the pattern perhaps have been `public static void(T obj, out ...)` so that it could be called with an on-stack value simply by doing `ldloc.a` of the targets?

Comment: @MarcGravell The `ldobj` [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANmgExAGoAfAAQCYBGAWAChyBmAAipYGEWBvBl/tq3IoWAOQAUASj4De9AQpYA3AIZQWAMwgQWAXhbimaFikkBuGYpYBZcdgB2m7ecssAvq9fM2I2w4MOGMaBkk4QoXJW/Krq4gjGAJ6h+loQFvICHvRuQA==). If you just access `Item1` directly it does an `ldfld` directly on the `&`, rather than copying it to the stack first.

Comment: I don't follow the pattern comment I'm afraid: `Deconstruct` on a value type uses `ldloca` anyway, as calling a static method is identical to calling a non-virtual method with "this" passed as the 0th arg.

Comment: @canton7 yes, that's why I'm wondering if the pattern is wrong :) in order to use `ldloca` (to get the `ref T` as `arg0` for the static call), it needs to first be: a formal local (and there needs to be a `stloc`); if we consider that deconstruction often happens on *return* values, it perhaps would have been better if the value could have been left intact, i.e. `[the call, leaving the value itself on the stack][load output targets][static call the deconstructor]`, hence `static void Deconstruct(T, out ...)` rather than `void Deconstruct(out ...)` - in the first, the T helpfully isn't `ref`

Comment: @MarcGravell Gotcha, I See what you're saying. The JIT [doesn't seem to mind](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBDAzgWwB8ABAJgEYBYAKGIGYACMhgYQYG8aHunHiUGAeQAUASi49O1HjIYA3bFAbCAlmgYArUQwC8DAOIwMAZTEBuCbKbkAnKoYBqTaIvSeAX0sMv9JgIAKYl5SVtwKSri6BkamLl4yxgB0ACIwkAB2uBhQAK5gGMK46hA5GPKKDGoMJWXhzq6h1nYqjvVenm7cPozG0SZiugB8DAAmMABm2DkANhiuHTS+sNgjEOnTAJ4MWbn5DMY0ITK+/AypGTt5BTXWAAyVxaV3zkPKVVpRwgBEpF/qX3QvnFOtwTuQkH4zmk1pd8sJehBgBpHmViOR7lUbmj7h8dMNVOpccofn8GACgWYeDR3EA===), though.

Comment: @canton7 fair enough; once again, we can marvel at how devious the JIT can be (btw, I made an edit re your `in` observation)